# org mode: how to reset files VISIBILITY state to that defined in STARTUP

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How to reset files VISIBILITY state to that defined in STARTUP, as if you closed and reopened file.
This would mean honouring each particular sections VISIBILITY property as well as that defined in STARTUP.
thanks!